# how to make template function (operator) deduce template arguments implicitly?

Tags: c++, templates, operators, template-argument-deduction

I have this code which I need to make it be compiled:

```
int main () {
    const Matrix<int, 3, 2> m1; // Creates 3*2 matrix, with all elements set to 0;
    Matrix<int, 3, 3> m2(4); // Creates 3*3 matrix, with all elements equals to 4;
    const Matrix<int, 3, 3> m3 = m2; // Copy constructor may take O(MN) and not O(1).
    cout << m3 * m1 << endl; // You can choose the format of matrix printing;
```

I already implemented the `operator<<` for the template matrix.
the problem is to implement `operator*` such that creating a new matrix with the template params of m3.rows and m1.cols, i.e. right return type in the signature of `operator*` result expression.

I tried:

```
Matrix<int, lhs.rows, rhs.cols> operator *(const MatrixBase& lhs, const MatrixBase& rhs)
Matrix<?> res; // not sure how to define it
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lhs.get_columns(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rhs.get_rows(); j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < lhs.get_columns(); k++)
            {
                res[i][j] = lhs[i][k] * rhs [k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the class MatrixBase is just a non-template abstract class that Matrix is derived from, a try to make `operator*` generic.
the problem is that `lhs` and `rhs` are not initialized yet and it does not compile, I thought of making the `operator*` as a method of Matrix but I am still stuck on the return type.
I know that template is determined with the preprocessor but I'm sure that there is a way to make it run.

Comment: You can't do it like that. C++ does not work this way. All template parameters must be compile-time `constexpr`s. You will need to redesign your code, in some way. Perhaps implement `operator*` in the `Matrix` template itself, instead of what is, apparently, some mysterious superclass called `MatrixBase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions lacks some information about what `MatrixBase` is, but if we just look at your `Matrix` class you need a template function to do this. There you can deduce the template parameters of the classes and use that to calculate the resulting type.

```
template <typename T, int LRows, int LCols, int RRows, int RCols>
Matrix<T, LRows, RCols> operator*(const Matrix<T, LRows, LCols>& lhs, const Matrix<T, RRows, RCols>& rhs) {
    static_assert(LCols == RRows, "Invalid matrix multiplication");
    Matrix<T, LRows, RCols> result;
    // ... do the calculations
    return result;
}
```

Comment: MatrixBase it's just the class all Matrix derived from, I did it to try to accept both lhs and rhs for every size but your solution is beautiful, worked like a magic, can you explain how the compiler creates the right 'operator*' from lhs/rhs template args?

Comment: It uses [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) to deduce the type of the passed in arguments at compile-time. This information can then be used as compile-time constants to do certain things, like in this case figure out the size of the resulting matrix. So every time you call the function with different arguments, the compiler will use this as it's prototype and generate a new function for those specific types. This means that each individual instatiation can have a different return type, that depends on the type of the parameter passed in.